# WiFi drivers not found, fast startup turned up on the Windows broken part

Tags: drivers, wireless

My device can't found any wifi drivers, unfortunately I turned to Ubuntu 20.04 after my Windows machine kept crashing and after turning on Fast Startup.

I have ethernet. Is there a way I can install the drivers and get the wifi?

I tried:

```
sudo apt install dkms
cd
git clone https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

but I don't have the wifi icon yet.

I checked mokutil --sb-state and it's false.

Here i my card:

```
antoi@antoi-Inspiron-3543:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Comment: Ethernet? Tether your phone?

Comment: Let's identify your exact card; please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`